# error installing hplip on ubuntu mate

Tags: ubuntu, plugin, mate-terminal

I am trying to install hplip in my Ubuntu Mate Zesty 17.04 machine from the terminal.

The hardware is HP LaserJet 1020 plus. I had previously downloaded the plugin from hplipopensource.com. The plugin downloaded was hplip-3.17.6.run and then I followed the instructions given in
 http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install/install/index.html

I get the following error (see attachment)

[image]

Comment: Can you paste the error in as text? Images are less useful.

Comment: `hplip` should be available in the repositories - have you tried that?

Comment: I tried using sudo apt-get install hplip. The installation proceeded without any error. Hwever, during printing, a dialog appears saying the required Hp plugin is not installed